# Edit field with date in .csv

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have .csv file with lines like this:

```
xxxx,xxxxxx,Sep  1, 2015 21:32:15.xxxxxxxxx WEST
xxxx,xxxxxx,Sep 28, 2015 23:46:16.xxxxxxxxx WEST
xxxx,xxxxxx,Sep 30, 2015 21:23:17.xxxxxxxxx WEST
```

and i need to change all date and time to this:

```
xxxx,xxxxxx,2015-09-01,21:32:15
xxxx,xxxxxx,2015-09-28,23:46:16
xxxx,xxxxxx,2015-09-30,21:23:17
```

I think it's possible using awk and date but until now nothing worked.

Comment: It is absolutely trivial with awk, no `date` required. Edit your question to show what you tried and in what was it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F, -lape '
  ($d2, $d1) = (pop(@F), pop(@F));
  $d2 =~ s/\..*//;
  push @F, Time::Piece->strptime($d1.$d2, "%b %e %Y %T")->strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%T");
  $_ = join ",", @F;
' file
```

That removes the last 2 comma-separated fields from each line, deletes the fractional time and timezone, reformats the time and prints.

Comment: Thank you. It worked even with the new example that wasn't mentioned at first time in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; mths="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec" }
{
    split($3,mthDay,/ +/)
    split($4,yrTime,/[ .]/)
    $3 = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", yrTime[2], (match(mths,mthDay[1])+2)/3, mthDay[2])
    $4 = yrTime[3]
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
xxxx,xxxxxx,2015-09-01,21:32:15
xxxx,xxxxxx,2015-09-28,23:46:16
xxxx,xxxxxx,2015-09-30,21:23:17
```

Comment: I edited the question and added new example because your solution didnt work on dates with single number because the file would have extra space between month and day instead of 0. On single day numbers 1 to 9 the result would always be 2015-10-00 instead of 2015-10-01 or 2015-10-09. Sorry for not giving a complete example at the start. Removing the extra space on single days from the file will make your solution work but i don't know how to do that automatically.

Comment: It just a tiny tweak to change `/ /` to `/ +/` in `split($3,mthDay,/ /)` to allow for multiple spaces between the month name and day number. I'm actually surprised you couldn't figure that out - the codes not that cryptic is it?